# Multiple Vlookups using VBA in one sub

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to fill multiple columns in a sheet with vlookups from another sheet named "Go Live Data" in the same workbook, to the end of the range.

So, based off of the value starting in A6 in my sheet, I want to lookup to range A:K in sheet "Go Live Data" for cells starting in U6 to the end of the data filled in the tab (this will change dynamically). I want to repeat this for cells starting with V6 and W6.

This is the code that I have now, but it does not populate.

```
Sub VlookupGoLiveandBOP()


Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range
Set Rng = Range(Range("A6"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
With Range("U6")
  .Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A6,Go Live 
Data!$A:$K,2,FALSE)),"""",VLOOKUP(A6,Go Live Data!$A:$K,2,FALSE))"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Rng.Offset(, 66)

With Range("v6")
  .Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A6,Go Live 
Data!$A:$K,3,FALSE)),"""",VLOOKUP(A6,Go Live Data!$A:$K,3,FALSE))"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Rng.Offset(, 66)


With Range("w6")
  .Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A6,Go Live 
Data!$A:$K,4,FALSE)),"""",VLOOKUP(A6,Go Live Data!$A:$K,4,FALSE))"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Rng.Offset(, 66)

End With
Rng.Offset(, 66).Value = Rng.Offset(, 66).Value

End Sub
```

Am I on the wrong track? Thank you for your help.

Comment: How is this code even compiling ? you have 3 `With` and only one `End With`

Comment: Sheet names with embedded spaces need to be enclosed in quotation marks (`'`)

Comment: There are also not allowed linebreaks in your `.Formula` lines (if they were not inserted by formatting the code on this site).

Comment: The `AutoFill` won't work either - but I'm not sure what you are trying to fill.  Perhaps `.AutoFill Destination:=.Resize(Rng.Rows.Count, 1)`

Comment: I wouldn't vlookup each time, I'd index and match for the row and offset accordingly.  You are vlookup-ing :) the same identifier, so have a helper column of match for the row and then use offset.  Your code only functions on 1 row any how, nothing dynamic, you may need to loop this for anything dynamic.  But what's the difference to just adding them and filling down with out code?

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below, it will help you assign the `VLookup` range correctly.

When using `LKUpRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal)` the 4th parameter `xlExternal` adds also the sheet's name (and workbook if needed) with all the `'` and `!` needed.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub VlookupGoLiveandBOP()

Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range
Dim LKUpRng As Range
Dim LkUpStr As String

Set LKUpRng = Sheets("Go Live Data").Range("A:K")    
LkUpStr = LKUpRng.Address(True, True, xlA1, xlExternal) '<-- get the Range as a String, including the sheet's name

Set Rng = Range(Range("A6"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

Range("U6").Formula = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A6," & LkUpStr & ",2,FALSE)),"""",VLOOKUP(A6," & LkUpStr & ",2,FALSE))"

End Sub
```

Comment: That definitely works, but it does not seem to populate all the way down to the end of the range? It just populates U6

Comment: I did'nt say I re-wrote the entire code, just helped you solve the issue raised, right ?

Comment: @cwight any feedback ? were you able to get the code to work ?